# If there are $5$ women and $5$ men, how many possibilities exist to form a committee of $3$ women and $2$ men.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I just wish to confirm if my understanding is correct for the following problem:

> If there are $5$ women and $5$ men, how many possibilities exist to form a committee of $3$ women and $2$ men.

So I have computed this problem as below:

$\binom{5}{3} \times\binom{5}{2} = 100$possibilities.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks good. Note that you have enough privilege to use [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $\binom{5}{3} \times \binom{5}{2} = 100$ is correct.